# Angular2 using subscriptions with route change

Tags: angular

I have found that my Angular2 subscription only fires upon page load. When I set up a `routerLink` away from and then to my **home.component** the `checkUser()` function does not launch.

For example, I set up a routerLink to a separate page (about). If, in my about page I set a routerLink back to my homepage, my `checkUser()` function from the **home.component** does not work.

What's the best way to get my subscriptions to work with these route changes?

My **home.component**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
private username$: FirebaseObjectObservable<string>;
private dashlink: boolean;
private logsub: Subscription;
  constructor(private mainService: MainService){
  }

  checkUser(){
        this.logsub = this.mainService.userThere$.subscribe( isUser => {
            if (isUser){
               alert("Yes");
            }
        });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.checkUser();
  }

}
```

Comment: What you've described sounds correct. ngOnInit should be called every time the route is hit. Perhaps related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can place any code needed for initialization in the `constructor` on each `class` (component class).

For your case, you want to place check user code inside the `constructor`, it will be called every time `HomeComponent` match the target route.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    private username$: FirebaseObjectObservable<string>;
    private dashlink: boolean;
    private logsub: Subscription;

    constructor(private mainService: MainService){
        // moving checkUser code inside constructor
        this.logsub = this.mainService.userThere$.subscribe( isUser => {
            if (isUser){
               alert("Yes");
            }
        });
    }
}
```